# Java generic bound by custom interface

Tags: java, class, generics, types, interface

I want to have a generic class A who's "value" can be only a JSON-serializable object. For this I chose to implement the interface myself. The issue is I want to avoid the following usage:

```
A a = new A("name", new BooleanType(false)); // I would like to just pass false as the argument
```

My setup is like:

```
Class A <T extends Type> {
    private String name;
    private T value;

    //getter...
}
```

--

```
Interface Type {
   Object value;
}
```

--

```
Class BooleanType implements Type {
    private Boolean value;

    public BooleanType(Boolean value){
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

other Type implementors...

One idea I had was to have a method for each Type in class A:

```
Class A <T extends Type> {
    private String name;
    private T value;

    public static A of(String name, Boolean value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //of implementations for Integer, LocalDatetime, etc

    //getter...
}
```

Can I achieve this without having multiple methods in A to create each different type?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the problem. To remove the upper bound requirement you need to remove the interface. You don't need an interface because all* objects and primitives are supported by Gson.

That being said, if you want to have class `A` allow for a key-value pair, you can have a parameter `V` represent the `value` and supply a default type. Then use the adapter pattern to implement that interface and compose it of the relevant object.

```java
interface MyType<V> {

    String name();
    
    V value();

}
```

```java
class MyTypeAdapter<V> implements MyType<V> {

    private final String name;

    private final V value;

    public MyTypeAdapter(String name, V value) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public V value() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```java
MyType<Boolean> myTypeAdapter = new MyTypeAdapter<>("foo", false);

boolean value = myTypeAdapter.value();
```